# prove $a^2<b^2$ if and only if $a<b; a,b\in N$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is an exercise in a textbook on number theory I am using for self study over break. I understand the converse implication ($a<b$ implies $a^2<b^2$) but am having trouble proving the other one. The textbook defines order as $x<y$ if $x+k=y,$ and we only have the natural numbers and the properties of: closure, commutativity, associativity, distributivity, the identity element, and cancelation laws. The only thing I can think of is to write $$a^2+k=b^2,$$ but then I have no way to show that $\sqrt{a^2+k}$ is a natural number, let alone that it is less than $b.$ The textbook is by Erickson and Vazzana.

Comment: Hint: $b^2 - a^2 = (b-a)(b+a)$, and $b+a > 0$ (except in the case $a+b=0$).

Comment: Thank you very much for this hint, but we don't have any concept of negative numbers yet, nor have we defined zero. All we have to prove this are the properties listed above and $a<b,b<c$ implies $a<c$

Comment: Whoa:  Don't get carried away with complications!  Consider what happens if $a$ is NOT $< b$.  That  means $a \ge b$.  So what does that say about $a^2$ and $b^2$.  Is $a^2 < b^2$ possible if $a \ge b$?

Answer (score 4):

Perfect example of a contrapositive.

$A \implies B$ is equivalent to (not $B) \implies ($ not $A)$.

Suppose $a^2 < b^2$.

Now either $a < b$ or $a = b$ or $b < a$.  If $a=b$ then $a^2 = b^2$ and that is impossible.  If $b < a$ then $b^2 < a^2$ and that is impossible.  So $a < b$ is the only possibility left.

In other words:

$a < b \implies a^2 = a*a < a*b < b*b = b^2$

And NOT ($a < b)\implies a \ge b \implies a^2 = a*a \ge b*a \ge b*b = b^2 \implies $NOT $(a^2 < b^2)$.

And that proves $a< b \iff a^2 < b^2$.

=====

Or to put it another way:

There are three possibilities.

1) $a < b$.

2) $a = b$

3) $b < a$.

If 1) then you have $a < b$ and $a^2 < b^2$.

If 2) then you have $a = b$ and $a^2 = b^2$

If 3) then you have $b < a$ and $b^2 < a^2$.

So in all three possibilities you have $a < b$ in the precise conditions and only in those conditions when $a^2 < b^2$.

And that is what "if and only if" means.

Answer (score 1):

If $$a<b$$ then $$ax<bx$$ for any positive $x$. Its easy to prove this from the definition. So we have 
Multiplying by $a$
$$a^2<ab$$ and by $b$,
$$ab<b^2$$ The result follows by transitivity.

Note that the reverse follows automatically, for either $a<b$, or $a=b$ or $b<a$ thus if $a^2<b^2$ you cannot have $b<a$, since then $b^2<a^2$.

Comment: The op said s/he understood $a < b \implies a^2 <b^2$.  It was $a^2 < b^2 \implies a < b$ that s/he didn't understand.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks, I edited.

Comment: Well, as long as I'm nitpicking.... you might also consider $a=b$...

Comment: @fleablood yeah I am assuming OP is smart enough to see that.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably a good call.

Answer (score 1):

Note:
$$a^2<b^2 \Rightarrow a^2+k=b^2 \Rightarrow a=\sqrt{a^2}<\sqrt{a^2+k}=\sqrt{b^2}=b.$$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/926528)

Comment: @XanderHenderson, I understand both OP's and your concerns. There is no need to prove $\sqrt{a^2+k}$ is a natural number... So this is an answer.

Comment: The OP's question is about *why* we don't need to show it (or why it isn't obvious).  You didn't address this at all.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

For the reverse implication, prove the contrapositive:  if $a\ge b$, then $a^2\ge b^2$.